# messed HTTPS for WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Hi i really messed my website. I followed this tutorial

https://make.wordpress.org/support/user-manual/web-publishing/https-for-wordpress/

I tried make my website url to https://www.kksa.lt and i done it. But it messed all website and now i can't access to wp-admin to change it back :(

My website is www.kksa.lt

**Please help ...**

Answer (score 0):

Solved my problem.
Basicly added these two line to my /wp-content/themes/enfold/functions.php

update_option('siteurl','http://example.com');
update_option('home','http://example.com');